# Как убрать checked с первого чекбокса и поставить на последний

Tags: javascript, html

Есть 4 чекбокса. Максимум может быть 2 выбранных. Когда выбраны 2 чекбокса, при клике на 3-й чекбокс, галочка должна убраться с 1-го и поставиться на 3-й чекбокс.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как это реализовать на чистом JS, без jQuery.

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox4" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
const container = document.getElementById('checkbox-container');
let values = [];
container.onchange = e => {
  const {target} = e;
  const {name, checked} = target;
  if (!checked) {
    values = values.filter(v => v != name);
  } else {
    values.push(name); // добавляем значение
    // оставляем только последние два элемента
    const unchecked = values.splice(0, values.length - 2);
    unchecked.forEach(u => {
      document.querySelector(`[name=${u}]`).checked = false;
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='checkbox-container'>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox4" />
</div>
```

Comment: Ничего не убирается.

Comment: а, блин, не так немного понял задание)))

Comment: @AlexSazonov, спасибо, я поправил)

Answer (score 3):

Вот так можно:

```js
let inputs = [...document.querySelectorAll('input')];
inputs.forEach(input => input.onclick = () => {
  // по клику ищем все инпуты с галочкой исключая тот, на который кликнули
  let other = inputs.filter(el => el.checked && el !== input)
  // если таких инпута уже 2, то снимаем галочку с первого из них
  other.length === 2 && (other[0].checked = false)
})
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox4" />
</div>
```

Comment: Чуть криво сработает, если кликать справа налево)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME в чем кривизна?

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME я интерпритировал индексы в вопросе не как порядок выполнения выбора, а как порядок на странице, а явного указания на это в вопросе нет